# Convert UDP header to TCP header

Tags: linux, tcp

I have a typical requirement, I want to have a converter module, that can convert UDP packet to TCP packet.
And I need to do it before the packet can be processed in IP layer.

I will explain this complete scenario using an example

Lets say we have 3 machines A, B and C.

1. A sent an UDP packet
2. B received UDP packet
3. At B, when packet is being given to IP layer (from Link / MAC / Ethernet layer) , I want to get hold of packet. I want to delete the UDP and IP header in packet. I want to add TCP and IP header (assuming C is the destination host).
4. Now from B machine, packet is sent to C machine

Can somebody help me how this can be done.
I am using linux machines.

Though libpcap can be one of the option (from wireshark), but it is not suitable for me because of performance reasons.
I want a very light weight solution for this problem.

Comment: Where are you going to get the sequence numbers from? and the connection?

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck? You could just open a raw socket for sending and receiving your packets. But your question doesn't sound like you are very familiar with the differences between UDP and TCP. I'm not sure if such a "conversion" is possible at all but if it is then it will require lots of work and hacks. It would be way easier to encapsulate UDP in TCP instead.

Comment: I didn't need these things. I want to capture the packet when it going from Ethernet Layer to IP layer.

Comment: Which "things"? Please be more precise.

Comment: Can I modify the NAT Firewall Sofware in order to do that. If possible suggest me some help.

Comment: sry, @scai that was not for you

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Perhaps you would get an answer if you could explain what it is you want to achieve. Simply changing headers is not going to work. UDP is connectionless, while TCP is connection oriented. E.G How would you even establish the TCP connection? In that case I would rather write a proxy that reads UDP packets and forwards them over an established TCP connection.

Comment: while encapsulation header part of different layer will be added with Application data(A Data) the way it proceeds ie first TLH(Transport Layer Header) say UDP will be attached then it will go to IP(Network Layer). At that point I want to hold the packet, remove the UDP header part ,insert TCP/IP header and transmit it to destination.

Comment: You didn't really answe the "why" part of the question. You can't simply convert one protocol to another one. Different protocols have different requirements, need different data to be exchanged, send different amounts of packets. TCP for example needs to perform a handshake before any data packets can be send. TCP also supports retransmits so you will need to implement a dynamic packet buffer and so on.

Comment: I got some information that we can do it with Linux NAT Firewall source code. If anybody knows anything about this i.e. where to get the source code?? Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Can't be done.  TCP is a stateful, reliable, connection-oriented byte-stream protocol.  UDP is a stateless, unreliable, unconnected packet protocol.

The best you can do is, on machine B, open a new socket/TCP connection to C, accept socket/UDP packets from A, and write the contents of those packets to the TCP stream.  Data flowing the other direction is a bit more difficult because you have to create UDP packets to A no larger than the maximum UDP packet size supported by your systems.

Comment: Umm lookup SCTP or even serial over IP

Comment: Most firewalls can also do this

Comment: Neither of those is a conversion of UDP to TCP.  You can send the data over a TCP stream or you can send the packets in their entirety over a TCP stream but you can't just change the header.  SCTP is a third protocol with some capabilities of both and is sort-of case #1.  Firewalls that do this are using a TCP-based VPN to fully encapsulate the UDP packets in the stream ala case #2; the other side parses and packetizes the stream, re-sending the UDP packets locally.

Comment: Your splitting hairs... And trying to seem smart in doing so... both are conversions by the very definition of such... And further more encapsulation yes but the encapsulation is not required... I can easily write a raw listener to recv and when I determine udp I can either convert or encapsulated it to tcp or vice versa.. soooo stfu and get a better edumacation... waterloo... kangsroo...wtf

Comment: The question is very specific:  Delete the UDP header and add a TCP header.  That is not possible.  Period.  All the other things you suggest are different things.  And my "education" comes from having written a complete, working, production TCP/UDP/IP stack from scratch, not from my school.

Comment: Just because your prod stack works doesn't mean anything... you can do what the op asks but you must have not understood... recv x udp, send , send x tcp, done... your schooling sounds like it produced a complete gap in knowledge... get your money back

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it directly but if you will use a **UDP VPN** than you can do it very easily.

Just connect you system/PC with **UDP VPN** network and it work as you are want.

check below my image for more information, i am also using same.

[image]